# Pass parser parameters when using CoreNLP server

Tags: stanford-nlp

The parser takes the flag `-makeCopulaHead`, how can I enable this flag on when using the [CoreNLP server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html)?

I've tried starting the server with the flag:

```
java -cp "*" -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -parse.flags " -makeCopulaHead"
```

I have also tried passing it the param as part of the url params in my post request:

```
properties = {"annotators": "...", "parse.makeCopulaHead": "true"}
properties = {"annotators": "...", "makeCopulaHead": "true"}
properties = {"annotators": "...", "parse.flags.makeCopulaHead": "true"}
```

**Edit**, and attempts from answer:

```
properties = {"annotators": "...", "parse.flags": " -makeCopulaHead"}
properties = {"annotators": "...", "parse.flags": "makeCopulaHead"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is the second: pass in the flags as `properties = {...}` entries. I don't actually know how this particular flag works, but it does seem like the equivalent to your command-line invocation would be:

```
properties = {"annotators": "...", "parse.flags": " -makeCopulaHead"}
```

Perhaps that'll work?

EDIT: The `-parse.flags` option will only work if you're using the constituency parser + dependency converter (annotator `parse`) rather than the neural dependency parser (annotator `depparse`).

Comment: Hmm, tried this just now. Doesn't seem to make any difference in the dependancies in the response.

Comment: What annotators are you running?

Comment: Ah, that's probably the issue. The `parse.flags` options is specific to the parser annotator (`parse`) and the associated dependency converter, rather than the dependency parser annotator (`depparse`). Try running with annotators `tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse`?

Comment: setting properties to `properties={"annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse", "parse.flags": " -makeCopulaHead"}` seems to give the same results (in the dependencies) as `properties={"annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse"}` alone.I'm using the sentence `He is tall` as a test case. The thing is that I need the dependancy information. The parse attribute shows as `SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE"`

Comment: If the parse attribute is `SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE`, then the parser annotator is not being run correctly. Not sure why, but the first thing you should try to debug is why there are no parse trees in the output when you set the parse annotator. Does restarting the server help?

Comment: Ok yes, I'd made a mistake entering the properties the 2nd time round - this does work. I found that the minimal properties I required were: `{"annotators": "lemma,parse,depparse", "parse.flags": " -makeCopulaHead"}`. I'll add a small comment about the annotator requirement to your answer as an edit and accept it. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: FWIW: You can't add options like this to depparse; you'd need to train a whole new parser model on dependency trees represented as makeCopulaHead. We haven't done that so far.